# Не работает go get для приватного репозитория

Tags: git, golang, ssh

Не могу воспользоваться `go get` для доступа к приватной репе:

```
go: git.***.ru/ap/database@v0.0.0-20201209100518-3ab668652e67/go.mod: verifying module: git.***.ru/ap/database@v0.0.0-20201209100518-3ab668652e67/go.mod: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/git.***.ru/ap/database@v0.0.0-20201209100518-3ab668652e67: 410 Gone
        server response:
        not found: git.***.ru/ap/database@v0.0.0-20201209100518-3ab668652e67: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/cc0b5d1e49db336d4983347fb72e737141f529166a29d68027e9e67dd35012d8: exit status 128:
                fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.***.ru': terminal prompts disabled
```

Comment: Странно, что там 410: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410

Comment: и что, [ничего не помогло?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27500861/4827341). особенно про GOPRIVATE, что должно, по идее помочь супротив `verifying module`